# get Security Group rules for every network interface with a public Ip

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, security, networking, amazon-ec2

I'm having troubles while trying to get some information with Boto3.
Here is what I want to do :

I loop over all network interfaces  in the AWS Account, if an interface is in use and it has a public IP, I get its security group and see if there is any rule opening flow to the internet like 0.0.0.0/0 or public IPs. The objective is to have a security report about all instances with network interfaces connection to the internet.

Here is the script:

```
# create dict
ip = {}
SGName = ''
SGID = ''
interfaceID = ''
ListGroups = {}
Message = 'Instances With Public Ips :'  
 # check aws profiles
for p in awsProfile:
    print(p)
    # define aws session
    session = Session(region_name="eu-west-1", profile_name=p)
    ec2 = session.resource('ec2')
    client = session.client('ec2')
    all_interfaces = ec2.network_interfaces.all()
    for interface in all_interfaces:
        interfaceID = interface.id
        desc = client.describe_network_interfaces(NetworkInterfaceIds=[interfaceID])
        for d in desc['NetworkInterfaces']:
            if interface.status == 'in-use' and d.get('Association') is not None:
                interfaceID = interface.id
                print(interfaceID)
                desc = client.describe_network_interfaces(NetworkInterfaceIds=[interfaceID])
                publicIp = d.get('Association')['PublicIp']
                SGName = d.get('Groups')[0].get('GroupName')
                SGID = d.get('Groups')[0].get('GroupId')
                ListGroups[SGName] = SGID
                Message = Message + str(p)+str(interface.vpc.id)+str(interface.attachment.get('InstanceId'))+str(interface.description)+str(interface.private_ip_address)+str(publicIp)+str(interfaceID)+str(SGID)+str(SGName)
                for key in ListGroups:
                    sg = ec2.SecurityGroup(ListGroups[key])
                    for i in range(len(sg.ip_permissions)):
                        for j in range(len(sg.ip_permissions[i]['IpRanges'])):
                            ip = IPNetwork(sg.ip_permissions[i]['IpRanges'][j]['CidrIp'])
                            if(ip.is_private()==False):
                                Message = Message + 'Public Securiy Groups details :'
                                Message = Message +str(ListGroups[key])+str(sg.ip_permissions[i]['ToPort'])
```

When I execute the script I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openNetwork.py", line 62, in <module>
    for i in range(len(sg.ip_permissions)):
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\factory.py", line 339, in property_loader
    self.load()
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\factory.py", line 505, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 310, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 599, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidGroup.NotFound) when calling the DescribeSecurityGroups operation: The security group 'sg-9abc52e3' d
oes not exist
```

It says that some security group does not exist. I'm supposed to get security group Ids that are attached to some network interface and that it exists. I tracked the network interface that get me to this error and it has 2 secutity groups either of them does not have this ID in the error. Any idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sole task is only to find security groups which might pose a security threat, head over to [AWS Trusted Advisor](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/trustedadvisor/). One of its core checks is for **Security Groups**:

> Checks security groups for rules that allow unrestricted access
>   (0.0.0.0/0) to specific ports. Unrestricted access increases
>   opportunities for malicious activity (hacking, denial-of-service
>   attacks, loss of data). The ports with highest risk are flagged red,
>   and those with less risk are flagged yellow. Ports flagged green are
>   typically used by applications that require unrestricted access, such
>   as HTTP and SMTP.